# Access violation writing location 0x00465004

Tags: assembly, masm, bubble-sort

I am writing the code for bubble sorting in assembly and my assembler is giving me "Access violation writing location" error inside the swap label. kindly help

```
INCLUDE irvine32.inc
.data
arr DWORD 8, 5,1,2,6
.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF arr
    sub ecx, 1
    mov ebx, LENGTHOF arr
    sub ebx, 1
    mov edx, 0
    l1:
        push ecx
        sub ebx, edx
        mov ecx, ebx
        mov esi, 0
        l2:
            mov eax, arr[esi]
            mov edi, arr[esi + TYPE arr]
            cmp edi, eax
            jle swap
            jmp done
            swap:
                mov arr[esi + TYPE arr], eax
                mov arr[esi], edi
        done:
        add esi, TYPE arr
        loop l2
        pop ecx
        add edx, 1
    loop l1
    exit
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Use a debugger to single step the code and see where it goes wrong. Anyway, the `sub ebx, edx; mov ecx, ebx` destroys `ebx`. You might want to try `mov ecx, ebx; sub ecx, edx` instead. There could be more problems,

Answer (score 1):

The problem is ebx was going negative with the repeated subtracts. There's no need to use ebx or edx. In case `arr` has length zero, after `sub ecx,1`, you can use `jb ...` to jump to `exit`.

```
main PROC
        mov ecx, LENGTHOF arr
        sub ecx, 1
        jb  exit0
    l1:
            push ecx
            mov esi, 0
        l2:
                mov eax, arr[esi]
                mov edi, arr[esi + TYPE arr]
                cmp edi, eax
                jg  noswap
                mov arr[esi + TYPE arr], eax
                mov arr[esi], edi
        noswap:
                add esi, TYPE arr
                loop l2
            pop ecx
            loop l1
    exit0:
        exit
main endp
        end main
```